# Woman knows a group of boys is taken over by aliens because they don't check out her breasts

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I started watching a sci-fi movie in late '90 or early '00 on a Finnish channel called MTV3. There was a crashed spacecraft in a forest, much like those you see in the northern parts of the world. A group of boys found it and explored it, they figured out it'd be good way to make cash if they show it to people asking for money. Can't remember how many there were in the group but at least two. Early teens.

Next they had people lining up to see it, I think. Eventually it attracted a team of agents or the like. I think there were three of them and atleast one of them was woman. They planned to check out the crashed ship pretending to be like any other curious person.
Before entering the ship, the woman opened up some top buttons from her shirt so anyone could get a good look at her breast.
After they had explored the ship, the woman told the other(s) that the boys have been taken over by aliens, when someone else asks her how does she know, she says it's because they didn't look at her breast.

The movie was most likely made in USA and maybe early or mid 90's.

Other detail I'm not so sure about, but the channel had a theme going around at the time where they showed some b-class movies of the "so bad it's good" variety, this one might've been shown during that time.

Comment: And a dupe of [Seeking alien invasion movie](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/103241/20774)

Comment: @Richard aw, that one didn't come up when I searched.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### You are looking for The Puppet Masters.

> The Earth is invaded by stingray-shaped alien "slugs" that ride on people's backs and control their minds. [Imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111003/)

Basically the woman agent says that because the boys / men didn't check her out (as her fellow male agent did) there is something off about them. This leads to them realizing they shouldn't go into the obviously fake UFO that the boys have constructed around the alien crash site (which is a vehicle (homonym) for infecting more humans).

I think later in the movie she undoes a couple of buttons in her blouse as a test and gets a similar disinterested reaction from infected people.

Comment: That was fast. Guess I didn't remember all the details correctly but I'm pretty sure it's that one.

Comment: @Relix I thought it was a decent enough scifi film and it had some good casting.