# ID movie where aliens control humans from behind

Tags: story-identification, alien-invasion, military-sf

Aliens were mass controlling every human being by jumping on their back and plugging in to the neck. It looked like this:

[image]

I can't remember anything but one scene, in which US soldiers were in a big hangar with their equipment, and had a video chat with the president. The president asked them to prove they were not being controlled by aliens, and a general said "No problem," started unbuttoning his shirt, and then turned around and the video signal was lost. (They cut off the video on purpose, because they actually were controlled.)

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127663/woman-knows-a-group-of-boys-is-taken-over-by-aliens-because-they-dont-check-out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Woman knows a group of boys is taken over by aliens because they don't check out her breasts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127663/woman-knows-a-group-of-boys-is-taken-over-by-aliens-because-they-dont-check-out)

Comment: Every movie adaptation of anything by Heinlein has been a horrific travesty, with only one exception: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_(film)

Answer (score 36):

I believe this is [the 1994 film adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Puppet_Masters_(film)) of Robert Heinlein's novel [The Puppet Masters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Puppet_Masters). While the president is a character in the movie, it's actually Donald Sutherland's character, a high-level intelligence agent, who teleconferences with the suspected military leaders. He asks a general to remove his shirt, and another military official (played by Yaphet Kotto) backs up his orders:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

...and just as the general he's speaking to on the teleconference begins to remove his shirt, the video cuts out:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I remembered the Heinlein novel as I was reading the question. In the novel version, I think the video link was to a young military officer on an orbiting space station. Somehow, the guy was utterly unable to let them see a nice clear image of his bare back, although he kept claiming he was trying his best . . .

Answer (score 5):

This look a bit like [Dark Skies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Skies).

> The series depicts The Hive as an alien species who are covertly invading Earth. They are a parasitic race of small multi-legged spider-like beings that can take control of host bodies, by attaching themselves to the brain.

Comment: iirc the ganglions there were inside the body, not visible from outside